# TimeLine Style Tab Bar Implementation Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, user-interface, mobile

I have been trying to find a approach for implementing this UI component. But so far no Luck.
Here's What I want, It is a tab bar which have 2 pages {basic details and registration details}
[image]

These two screens contains Forms with a submit button at bottom.
Until User submit the basic details form he/she gets access to registration page not before then.

Moreover, the implementation of the design is the main issue not the functionality.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you could use the material [Stepper](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Stepper-class.html) class with a `type` of `StepperType.horizontal`.